# Меня поставил в тупик яндекс... Таможня

Tags: склонение, падежи

Начал узнавать про таможенное оформление...

Вбиваю в Яндекс "Таможенное оформление на Московской областной таможне" (это не мною написано — я скопировал заголовок из статьи), а он исправляет на "Таможенное оформление на Московской областной таможнИ".

Начал искать проверочные слова и правила падежей и склонений и запутался в конец — как правильно в данном предложении: "таможне" или "таможни"? Даже поругался с супругой... Помогите: как правильно пишется слово в контексте этого предложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш первоначальный запрос корректен.

"[на Московской областной таможни](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%22)" 2 результата
"[на Московской областной таможне](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%22)" 855 результатов
У яндекса свои алгоритмы. Если хотите проверить его грамотность, то возьмите Ваш поисковый запрос в кавычки. 
Предлоги, по большому счёту, поисковыми системами игнорируются (если не указать, чтобы они принимались во внимание явно, посредством соответствующего оператора, если мне не изменяет память, то это "+"), а так как количество результатов по запросу "[Московской областной таможни](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%22)" больше, чем по запросу "[Московской областной таможне](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%22)" 37 600 против 8 940 (на примере гугла, в яндексе, думаю, аналогично), то поисковой движок и "корректирует" Ваш запрос.

Также, возможно, Вам будет интересно в этой связи ознакомиться с языком поисковых запросов [тут](http://semyadro.pro/osnovy/yazyk-poiskovykh-zaprosov-17) или же на [официальном сайте](https://yandex.ru/support/search/query-language/search-context.html).

Comment: А пуля пролетела...

Comment: Спасибо, не учел, что они игнорируют данный момент!

Answer (score 2):

*"Таможенное оформление на Московской областной таможне"*  - это верно, окончание -Е (1 скл., П.п).

Видимо, какой-то сбой был, это же машина, бывает, что и глючит... У меня тоже бывало, что правильное на неправильное исправлялось. Зачем же в собственной грамотности сомневаться в таких-то лёгких случаях...